# File locking between server threads

Tags: c, locking, socket, file, server

I have written the below code where the server is getting requests from clients on a socket and creating a thread per client. Each client thread is then writing to a file which is common to all the threads. The file has been `open`ed when main starts, so the same `fd` is being used by each thread. In such a scenario I have tried to achieve locking on file when one thread is writing to it. Since the threads are of same process so `flock` can't simply lock the file, hence `mutex` is used.

```
/*Logging function*/
void write_to_file(int op_fd,char *name)
{
   flock(op_fd,LOCK_EX);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&f_lck);
      write(op_fd,name,20);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&f_lck);
   flock(op_fd,LOCK_UN);
}

/*Client thread function*/

void *clnt_thread(void * arg)
{
  int this_fd=*(int *)arg;
  /*str is a continuous memory array of the size of the dat_com struct.This will be filled up initially on receive as a normal array
   , but then it'll typecasted to point to struct dat_com object*/
  char str[sizeof(dat_com)],str_send[25];

  memset(&str,'\0',sizeof(str));
  dat_com *incm_dat;    // struct to contain the incoming data from client .

  while(1)
  {
  read(this_fd,str,sizeof(str));
  /*typecast to struct dat_com so that it is ready to be inserted into linked list or file.*/
  incm_dat=(dat_com *)&str;

   if(strncmp(str,"quit",4)==0)
    break;

  /*Call write to file function*/
  write_to_file(o_fd,incm_dat->name);
  fprintf(stderr,"Client said: %s",incm_dat->name);

  /*client wants to close connection?*/

  sprintf(str_send,"%s",incm_dat->name);
  send(this_fd,str_send,sizeof(incm_dat->name),MSG_NOSIGNAL);
  }
close(this_fd);
return 0;
}
```

This is working as expected at the moment. Is it good practice to lock this way, or is there any other best practice? If I have to put this code into production, what changes should I make that are not standard practice?

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to use `flock` **and**  a mutex, unless you are sharing
with another process (as opposed to thread).  I would just use the mutex and
remember to check the return values from the `pthread_*` and `write` calls.

Some other comments:

- `name` in `write_to_file` should be `const` and the `write` call in that
  function should use the length of the name, not an assumed 20.
- you need to check the status of function calls (`read`, `write`, `send`
  etc).
- depending upon where the data being written is coming from and what it
  contains, you may have byte-ordering problems that are not handled.
- Since you are mixing string data and `dat_com` structures on the socket, you
  risk getting them mixed up.  You'd be better sticking with one format, maybe
  strings and have a way to check alignment and log/recover-from errors.
- Your `fprint` calls are not synchronized across threads and may end up
  interleaved.
- When sending the name, there is no need to copy it into a string first.

  ```
  sprintf(str_send,"%s",incm_dat->name);
  send(this_fd,str_send,sizeof(incm_dat->name),MSG_NOSIGNAL);
  ```

  just send it directly:

  ```
  send(this_fd, incm_dat->name, strlen(incm_dat->name), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
  ```
- Your variable and type names are poorly chosen.  `dat_com` means little,
  `this_fd` should be just `fd`, `incm_dat` could be just `data`, `o_fd` as a
  global should be longer and more descriptive of function.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions ! I didn't get your fourth point(..mixing string data and dat_com structures..). Bcz what I have known is we can't directly read a structure from socket, hence I read same amount of bytes and then type casted.

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce a layer in between your threads and the file.

E.g. have a thread that handles all writing to the file, it holds a mutex protected queue which is written by the other two threads. That way you have a layer between the physical file (slow access) and the queue (fast access). You then do not have to lock the file in any way since only the thread that writes the file needs to have access to it.

---